# Avoid AVPlayer and UIWebView play music in the same time

Tags: ios, avfoundation, avplayer

Thanks for noticing this question. I am using a singleton to play music in my app, via `AVPlayer`, like this way:

```
AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
[session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
[session setActive:YES error:nil];

AVURLAsset *musicAsset    = [[AVURLAsset alloc] initWithURL:url options:nil];
AVPlayerItem *playerItem = [AVPlayerItem playerItemWithAsset:musicAsset];

AVPlayer *player = [AVPlayer playerWithPlayerItem:_playerItem];

player.actionAtItemEnd = AVPlayerActionAtItemEndNone;

[player play];
```

It works fine. But my app has some music pages(HTML5), so user can also visit the web page, and play music there. The music from `UIWebView` and from `AVPlayer` can be played in the same time, seems to be very strange. Is there any ways to detecting if `UIWebView` will playing music, so I can stop the native `AVPlayer`? Thanks!

Comment: Hi Hang, do you have solution about that?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried listening for AVPlayerItemBecameCurrentNotification?  When your webpage launches a media file (video or audio), this will be fired.  You can intercept it as follows:

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                         selector:@selector(avPlayerItemBecameCurrent:)
                                             name:@"AVPlayerItemBecameCurrentNotification"
                                           object:nil];
```

Now (and I realise I'm teaching you to suck eggs here - my apologies.  This is just for completeness) you need avPlayerItemBecameCurrent:

```
-(void)avPlayerItemBecameCurrent:(NSNotification*)notification
{
    // Your code goes here to stop your native AVPlayer from playing.
}
```

Caveat - I haven't tested this, but it should work.

(Having written this, and after digging around a little more, I found this [Detecting and intercepting video playback in UIWebView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26047694/detecting-and-intercepting-video-playback-in-uiwebview/26155412#26155412))